# Shadows are not getting rendered properly

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, shadows

[image: Screenshot]

I am new to blender and trying to render an image. However in the render, the shadows which are visible in viewport are not displayed. I tried searching a lot, but unable to get what is it I am doing wrong. I have gone through the Scene settings but could not figure out what it is that I am not doing correctly while rendering( my assumption is also coming from the fact that the 'bolt' also looks different in the render ). I am using Cycles for render, if that needs to be handled differently.

Any guidance/direction will really help.

Blend file - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M3Pnu-q4lVjWPIC_dEq86C6KqZrAK8-k/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have Scene world turn it off, that is a setting to turn an HDRI for the viewport only but not for the render. To have an HDRI for the render, you need to add an HDR Image to the world nodes. [See this](https://youtu.be/JM-Z4F3WtmI?t=81)

[image]

When you turn that on, you will see the render as it is.

[image]

You also change some setting for your sun Light, like the angle and color which also affects the shadows,

Comment: thanks a lot!!!   also, can you direct me, why the bolt is rendered differently. The screw modifier does not look the same in render. Thanks once again.